# Combine minimum and second minimum in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have following query to calculate the first upcoming business date, which looks like the following:

```
SELECT LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES.ACCT_NBR, MIN(BUSINESS_DATES.DATE_VALUE) AS FIRST_BUSINESS_DAY
FROM BUSINESS_DATES JOIN SD_CALENDAR ON BUSINESS_DATES.CODE = SD_CALENDAR.CODE
    JOIN  AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF ON AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.CALENDAR_ID = SD_CALENDAR.ID
    JOIN SD_ACCT_GRP ON AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.ACCT_GRP_ID = SD_ACCT_GRP.ID
    JOIN SD_ACCT_GRP_MEMBER ON SD_ACCT_GRP.ID = SD_ACCT_GRP_MEMBER.GRP_ID
    JOIN SD_ACCT ON SD_ACCT.ID = SD_ACCT_GRP_MEMBER.ACCT_ID
    JOIN LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES ON SD_ACCT.ACCT_NBR = LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES.ACCT_NBR
WHERE BUSINESS_DATES.DATE_VALUE > LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES.BAL_DATE
GROUP BY LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES.ACCT_NBR
```

Now I want to also have a column with the second upcoming business date. I want this in the same sql query. How can I make a select to have the minimal and second minimal?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use rownumber with CTE..

    ;with cte
    as
    (SELECT LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES.ACCT_NBR, row_number() over ( order by  BUSINESS_DATES.DATE_VALUE ) AS FIRST_BUSINESS_DAY
    FROM BUSINESS_DATES JOIN SD_CALENDAR ON BUSINESS_DATES.CODE = SD_CALENDAR.CODE
        JOIN  AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF ON AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.CALENDAR_ID = SD_CALENDAR.ID
        JOIN SD_ACCT_GRP ON AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.ACCT_GRP_ID = SD_ACCT_GRP.ID
        JOIN SD_ACCT_GRP_MEMBER ON SD_ACCT_GRP.ID = SD_ACCT_GRP_MEMBER.GRP_ID
        JOIN SD_ACCT ON SD_ACCT.ID = SD_ACCT_GRP_MEMBER.ACCT_ID
        JOIN LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES ON SD_ACCT.ACCT_NBR = LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES.ACCT_NBR
    WHERE BUSINESS_DATES.DATE_VALUE > LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES.BAL_DATE
    GROUP BY LAST_CLOSING_BALANCE_DATES.ACCT_NBR
    )
    select ACCT_NBR,
min(DATE_VALUE) as firstbusiness,
max(DATE_VALUE)as secondbusiness from cte where rn<=2
group by ACCT_NBR
```